# Sorting a fetched results controller, empty strings last

Tags: objective-c, sorting, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nssortdescriptor

Let's say I have a `Person` entity in a Core Data store. I have a `UITableView` populated by an `NSFetchedResultsController` that shows every `Person` entity. Naturally, the `Person` entity has a `name` property, which is optional. We want to display the list alphabetically, A-Z. Users who see this want to look at named persons first, as those are the ones they'll care more about. So the sort descriptor that the controller takes in its initializer must show `Person` entities with non-null names first, then null names.

My options are limited. I'm only allowed to use certain comparators that are provided on `NSString` when hitting the database, none of which meet my criteria. I can't sort on transient values. I've tried using a zero-width whitespace as a default value, but Core Data apparently trims the whitespace out. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

The sections in the fetchedResultsController do not need to correspond one-to-one with the sections that you are displaying in the your tableview.  Right now you have sections something like (null), A, B, C, D,...etc.  But you can change how your view controller choose to display the sections. Set section 0 in your tableview looks at section 1 in the fetchedResultsController and 1->2, 2->3...until the last section (the no names section) points to section 0.

This is not that complicated but it can add a mess to your code.  So I would recommend creating a separate object that deals with converting the fetchedResultsController indexPaths and sections to your tableview's indexPaths and sections.  (Also make sure to deal with the case that there is no "no name" section, and when there is only a "no name" section).

If that seems too complicated, a simpler solution would be to add a property of `hasName` and sort by that first. Make a custom setter for the person's name that will also set the `hasName` property so you can easily keep this property in sync.

Comment: I only display the names in one section, but the `hasName` suggestion sounds like it could work.